# How do I (deterministically) cache a function returning a Dask dataframe in a chunked fashion?

Tags: python, pandas, caching, dask, dask-dataframe

I'd like to deterministically cache arbitrary functions that return [Dask dataframes](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html), into parquet files, in a chunked fashion. I say "deterministically" to distinguish this from Dask's [opportunistic caching](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/caching.html) mechanism, which is great but not what I'm looking for.

So far, I have this decorator that implements the caching mechanism I want, but in a non-chunked fashion:

```py
import base64
from functools import wraps
import hashlib
import json
from pathlib import Path

import dask.dataframe as dd

def ezhash(o):
    o = json.dumps(o, sort_keys=True)
    o = hashlib.md5(o.encode('utf-8')).digest()
    o = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(o).decode('ascii')
    return o

def cached_compute(enabled=True, engine='pyarrow', write_kwargs={}, read_kwargs={}):
    def _cached_compute(f):
        """
        Either compute and cache function f, or get its cached value
        operates out-of-core
        adds a named parameter input_state to f
        :param f: The function to cache
            f must return a (lazy) dask container containing parquet-serializable dtypes
            if any column is not parquet-serializable (in particular, array objects), you get errors like this:
                ValueError: Error converting column "page_ssb" to bytes using encoding UTF8.
                Original error: bad argument type for built-in operation
        :param input_state: Optional input state to cache, instead of caching f's arguments
            if input_state is not given: compute key from f's name and arguments
            if input_state is given: compute key from f's name and input_state
        """
        @wraps(f)
        def g(*args, input_state=None, **kwargs):
            if not enabled:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            if input_state == None:
                key = ezhash({'name': f.__name__, 'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs})
            else:
                key = ezhash({'name': f.__name__, 'input_state': input_state})
            key_path = Path(f'parquet_cache/{key}/')
            cache_keys = [path.name for path in Path('parquet_cache').glob('*')]
            if key not in cache_keys:
                print(f'caching to {key}')
                res = f(*args, **kwargs)
                res.to_parquet(key_path, engine=engine, **write_kwargs)
            print(f'reading cache {key}')
            res = dd.read_parquet(key_path, engine=engine, **read_kwargs)
            return key, res
        return g
    return _cached_compute
```

This works well to cache the overall results of functions returning Dask dataframes. However, now I'm grappling with a function that does a network call, meaning it might intermittently fail. I now would like the above caching mechanism to cache results per-line or per-chunk, such that re-running the function will load the cached lines/chunks but retry the function on the failed lines/chunks (and subsequently cache the results).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

## Update 2021-10-05: Add expected inputs and outputs

Append the following test code to the above:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

def network_call(row):
    """Simulate a network call"""
    if random.random() > 0.9:
        # success 90%
        response = sum(row.tolist())
    else:
        # fail 10%
        response = None
    row['response'] = response
    return row

def run_example(cache_enabled, max_runs=5):
    def expensive_function(input_data):
        ddf = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(input_data), npartitions=4)
        ddf = ddf.apply(network_call, axis=1, meta={k: 'int64' for k in [*input_data.keys(), 'response']})
        return ddf

    if cache_enabled:
        # apply caching decorator
        expensive_function = cached_compute(write_kwargs={'schema': 'infer'})(expensive_function)

    input_data = {
        'col_1': list(range(  0, 100)),
        'col_2': list(range(100, 200)),
        'col_3': list(range(200, 300)),
    }

    prev_success = 0
    for i_run in range(max_runs):
        if cache_enabled:
            _, ddf = expensive_function(input_data)
        else:
            ddf = expensive_function(input_data)
        n_success = sum(ddf['response'].isna() > 0)
        print(f'''Run #{i_run + 1:>2}: Total successes {n_success:>3}/100 (+{n_success - prev_success:>2})''')
        prev_success = n_success

print('''Running with cache disabled''')
run_example(cache_enabled=False)

print('''\nRunning with cache enabled''')
run_example(cache_enabled=True)
```

Run it:

```
$ python test_.py 
Running with cache disabled
Run # 1: Total successes  92/100 (+92)
Run # 2: Total successes  92/100 (+ 0)
Run # 3: Total successes  97/100 (+ 5)
Run # 4: Total successes  92/100 (+-5)
Run # 5: Total successes  90/100 (+-2)

Running with cache enabled
caching to 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 1: Total successes  89/100 (+89)
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 2: Total successes  89/100 (+ 0)
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 3: Total successes  89/100 (+ 0)
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 4: Total successes  89/100 (+ 0)
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 5: Total successes  89/100 (+ 0)
```

Observe how the caching mechanism currently just loads the first run's results regardless of success, and how it does not re-run failed computations.

A successful answer to this question should result in something like this:

```
caching to 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 1: Total successes  89/100 (+89)
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 2: Total successes  98/100 (+ 9)
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 3: Total successes 100/100 (+ 2)
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 4: Total successes 100/100 (+ 0)
reading cache 9Egrh7PYPHO2yoGMnNCBpg==
Run # 5: Total successes 100/100 (+ 0)
```

Comment: Do you mind to write an example with original dataframe and expected output?

Comment: Updated the question with an example.

Comment: I don't think dask can do this right now, I'd suggest filing a feature request to get more eyes on this question: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type%2Ffeature%2Cneeds-triage&template=feature-request.md

Comment: No, the Dask authors are clear that questions like these belong in SO. I'll leave this here for now.